# how to efficiently download a file from rest api and send it to a message brocker like RabbitMq?

Tags: java, spring, rest

the objective is to download a file from a URI and map it to an existing data model. this data model called `FileNode` and has a property with type `InputStream` (this `InputStream` represents the file data). I do not know how to do this. I tried to use Spring `RestTemplate`, but it closes the response `InputStream` in its `doExecute` method (all `RestTemplate` template methods eventually delegates to this method). then I tried to extend RestTemplate and comment the code that closes the Response InputStream :

```
  @Override
  protected <T> T doExecute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback, ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor) throws RestClientException {
    Assert.notNull(url, "URI is required");
    Assert.notNull(method, "HttpMethod is required");
    ClientHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
      ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);
      if (requestCallback != null) {
        requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
      }
      response = request.execute();
      handleResponse(url, method, response);
      return (responseExtractor != null ? responseExtractor.extractData(response) : null);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      String resource = url.toString();
      String query = url.getRawQuery();
      resource = (query != null ? resource.substring(0, resource.indexOf('?')) : resource);
      throw new ResourceAccessException("I/O error on " + method.name() +
        " request for \"" + resource + "\": " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    finally {
      /**** when to close the response? can I use a proxy for the response's InputStream that closes this response when itself is closed?****/
      if(!(responseExtractor instanceof CloseableResponseExtractor)) //?!
      if (response != null) {
        response.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

then I was thinking it should be a simpler way to do this, so I posted this question.

**note:** I send the file immediately to a message broker, I mean I do not have to save it in memory. and I do not think it is good idea to save the file in memory or disk and then stream from there because the file size might be too large, I do not know! in fact, my code must be a very thin layer between the infrastructure (legacy codes + message broker+...) and the rest API, and I think if I first write it to disk it impacts the response time severely (I need to write and read from disk!). what are your recommendations?

what is the best practice for this scenario and usually how this is done?

thank you!

Comment: Should REST API put message to broker immidiately or there can be a delay?

Comment: yes immediately.